# Monotony and convexity?

Tags: analysis, derivatives

I have a function that is strictly monotonous on $[0,\infty)$ and $f(0)=0$. The question is whether the derivative of the function is convex.

My first thought was, there is not enough data to know that. But I realized I couldn't really think of a function that would be concave and satisfy upper conditions. My first thought was $\sqrt x$ but it is not derivable in $0$. Could I somehow extend it to make it derivable at 0? Is there any other function that would work?

Comment: please use tex to type your questions. Have a look at your question and to others questions via clicking on "edit" and see how you can type it correctly. About your question just take $y=x^2$, but clearly not all increasing funtions are convex or concave. Only a handful portion of them are convex..

Comment: Wording tip: To say a function has a derivative at a point is to say it is differentiable there.

Comment: $\sqrt{x+1}$?  $\sqrt{x+2}$?

Comment: @Michael that doesn't satisfy $f(0)=0$

Comment: So you can just shift it down if you like: $-1+\sqrt{x+1}$.